# How i can get content link from URL and then get content of a single div of my geted link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the jquery code bellow. I want to get the content link from URL and then I want to load the content of a div from that URL. I have got the content link as link variable and I have the div named #myDiv with the variable div. I want to load contents only from the div named #myDiv. but it loading the full webpage please help me.

```js
function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
}

var link = GetURLParameter('link');
var div = '#myDiv';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').load(link, div);

});
```

Comment: Can you please add your html and add all your code to some sort of fiddler (e.g https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/jquery)?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, you may want to explain it better.     So.. u have a link address passed from url params and u want to show that link as text in a div?  if so try this:  $("#lmyDiv").html( link );

Comment: i have uploaded my files in a zip file to google drive. please download the zip file and see the files, link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13iTxBqgOJ089NImyOoDJd7SNwyxZyMdt/view?usp=drivesdk